# Dropbox Core API Library with DbxFileSystem and background sync [Android]

Tags: android, dropbox, dropbox-api

Dropbox's Sync API for android seems very nice, especially with its [DbxFileSystem](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/sync/docs/android#com.dropbox.sync.android.DbxFileSystem) that makes it look like a local file system while syncing is automatically done in the background. However, for some reason, Sync API doesn't allow access to a user's full dropbox, only select files or folders. It seems like for that case I need to use Core API.

Has anybody created a library that emulates DbxFileSystem functionality and background syncing built on the Core API?

Comment: also I'm curious as to why Dropbox wouldn't allow the Sync API to have full access. Seems like it's just making it harder for developers...